# Vue augmented types - XYZ does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using vue class component with typescript and I need to augment the types to use a third party module.

component

```
export default class TestComponent extends Vue  {

   private created() {
     this.$snotify.success('test')
   }
}
```

shims.d.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Snotify } from 'vue-snotify'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface VueConstructor {
      $snotify: Snotify
    }
  }
```

"Property $snotify does not exist on type TestComponent"

Vue.$snotify exists, but this.$snotify does not even though this extends Vue

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try augmenting the `Vue` type instead of `VueConstructor`:

```ts
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $snotify: Snotify
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to actually work, instead check out @RomainLanz's answer on [a related vue-snotify GitHub issue](https://github.com/artemsky/vue-snotify/issues/74#issuecomment-479409854):

> ```
> import Vue from 'vue'
> import { SnotifyService } from 'vue-snotify/SnotifyService'
>
> declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
>   interface Vue {
>     $snotify: SnotifyService
>   }
> }
> ```

Adding this answer here because this was one of the pages that came up when searching for the same thing.

Comment: While it's certainly useful to cross-reference related, authoritative threads, isn't this effectively the same solution that @Decade-Moon offered a couple of years ago?

Comment: It isn't. Mainly due to the fact that it's not entirely clear what to import and that the type itself will throw a ts error when attempting to compile. Its specifically { SnotifyService } that should be used as the type in order for it to work as the docs indicate it should.

Comment: Aha! That’s a useful point to call out. Thank you. Would you mind updating your answer to include that? It’s useful to differentiate similar answers to help users skimming a thread to quickly find the appropriate solution.